# How to add menubar in my program with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, menubar

I managed to create the menubar in the menu editor by clicking and writing text to each menu item i wanted.

I cant see any button to get the code to include the menu in my program.

How i can get this menu working?

C++

Comment: What language are you building your application in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depends on whether you are using pure win32 api or MFC. But being a newbie i will first assume that you are using win32 api. do a simple google search for forgers win32 tutorials.

just to satisify you, edit the main.cpp file and change the WNDCLASSEX structure, under the lpszMenuName part.

See, you just cant keep using visual studio's code generation features. You have to understand the code behind the menu, and it is not hard. other wise you will never understand the more advanced features. No offence but these things are covered all over the internet.

Comment: thanks, got it working by adding: wc.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1);